# How to just change the background color of Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have built app which theme color is light blue. I want that when I click on `EditText` to write something the background color of the keyboard should be the same.

I have found many solutions and all are the same that is creating a custom keyboard.

1. So how can I change the keyboard color without creating a custom keyboard?
2. If custom keyboard is the only option then please provide us with few example for which I don't have to make so many changes as I am trying to make a very light app (within 1.5 MB)

Comment: "So how can I change the keyboard color without creating a custom keyboard?" -- you can't. The input method editor (IME) that the user chose was written by other programmers. There does not even have to *be* a background, let alone one that apps like yours can affect. Moreover, even if you *do* create an IME, few will use it, as users need to manually choose to switch to yours.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got your point. So now what I have to do to create custom keyboard which all will look like default keyboard but only with different background color.

Comment: "which all will look like default keyboard" -- that's not possible. There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. These ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of "default keyboard" implementations. All do not look alike. All do not have the same features. What you will wind up creating is an IME that is different than what most people are used to, and typically with fewer capabilities (e.g., less support for different languages).

Comment: @CommonsWare You mean to say I have to build custom keyboard from scratch (create keyboard layout file, write a code for.each key, perform event on each key, give design). Hence can I find readymade keyboard of which I can change background color and I can add this in our app, any library or any other way to do it?

Comment: @CommonsWare is there any library available which I can add as a module in my app and can change the background color of keyboard?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam." (from [the site documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)). And, I have explained, you cannot change the background color of an input method editor supplied by another app.